# Django response middleware?

Tags: django

In Django, Middlewares are those which alter a set of request before any business logic is applied.My question is are there any middleware or any concept which is applied after request is processed by a view? Ex: response middleware

Comment: Why do you say middleware is run before the request? The [middleware documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/middleware/#hooks-and-application-order) specifically notes the different points it is called, which includes both request and response stages among others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django middleware can handle both alter the request in `process_request`/`process_view` and alter the response in `process_response`. Note that the `process_response` are run in the opposite order as the `process_request` hooks. There is a nice diagram in the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/middleware/#hooks-and-application-order

Comment: Is there a end to end diagram where a request is passed through webserver,mod wsgi ,Django and responded back

Comment: Not that I know of but I don't see why that's relevant for this question.

Comment: It wasnt relevant but i just wanted to know if there is any? Or canu indicate how it is done so?

Comment: There was a recent PyCon video on this topic: http://pyvideo.org/video/2644/a-scenic-drive-through-the-django-request-respons